# Hashing a password before form submission in IE9

Tags: javascript, hash, internet-explorer-9

I have implemented the example given in this article for one of my websites: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

All was well until IE9 users started reporting that they could not log in to the site. Users HAVE javascript enabled but I still could not work out why this was happening. The same users can log in using other browsers, so it's not a case of forgotten password either (which I very much suspected!)

The formhash function was written exactly as it appeared in the article (very annoying copying it from an image!)

```
function formhash(form, password) {
  console.log("Hashing form");
  // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field.
  var p = document.createElement("input");
  // Add the new element to our form.
  form.appendChild(p);
  p.name = "p";
  p.type = "hidden"
  p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
  // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
  password.value = "";
  // Finally submit the form.
  form.submit();
}
```

No errors are reported upon submission, so it doesn't appear to be anything not being supported by IE9. So what's going wrong with this hashing function?

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but if you're concerned about sending passwords over a network why not use SSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that IE9 doesn't like modifying form inputs, as such you have to set the value BEFORE adding the element to the DOM

```
function formhash(form, password) {
  console.log("Hashing form");
  // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field.
  var p = document.createElement("input");
  p.name = "p";
  p.type = "hidden"
  p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

  // NOW, add the new element to our form.
  form.appendChild(p);

  // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
  password.value = "";
  // Finally submit the form.
  form.submit();
}
```

Credit to [this poor soul](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/431242/javascript-not-working-in-ie-but-perfect-in-ff-gcsafari#post1848203) who was experiencing my exact problem